# Uncaught Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a uncaught JavaScript error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function games.html:37
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="slide_1()">
  <img id="slide_1" class="slide_preview" height="50" src="images/slide_1.jpg" />
</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var slide_count = 1

function slide_1() {
    slide_count = 1;
    document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundImage=slide_1;
        document.getElementById("slide_2").className="slide_preview";
        document.getElementById("slide_3").className="slide_preview";
        document.getElementById("slide_4").className="slide_preview";
        document.getElementById("slide_5").className="slide_preview";
        document.getElementById("slide_1").className="slide_preview active";
}
function slide_2() {
        ...
}
```

The slide functions go up to 5, as you might be able to tell by the `getElementById("...")`

Comment: Post a proper example of the code which replicates the problem, http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

My **guess** is that the problem is due to this line...

```
document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundImage=slide_1;
```

... because you are setting the `backgroundImage` property to a reference of the **function** `slide_1`.

You appear to have an element in your document called `slide_1` as well... which is probably what you're trying to set the backgroundImage to... but I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundImage=slide_1
```

You trying set function as background image. (slide_1 is a function, not image url)

Comment: its a string variable with the link within that string